# AIR Mobile Embedded Font

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to change the default font of a text field in an AIR Mobile app.
What I dos first embed the font using this line:

```
[Embed(source='C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/ARIAL.TTF', fontName="_Arial", mimeType="application/x-font-truetype")]
```

After that, I create a `TextFormat` with this font: `style.font = "_Arial";` and set it to the text field: `tf.setTextFormat(style);`

Sadly, the font does not change.
Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are not forgetting anything ? how about declaring a "font-face" ?  check this samples @font-face {
    src: url("../assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
tf.defaultTextFormat = style;
```

There are differenced between `defaultTextFormat` and `setTextFormat`

[setTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29)

[defaultTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat)

**UPDATE:**

not sure why this is not working what you have there, but i managed to make it working, just replace the font embedding line with this:

```
[Embed(systemFont="Arial", fontName="_Arial", mimeType="application/x-font-truetype", embedAsCFF="false")]
```

Comment: This had some interesting effects where the size was not taken into consideration. I added a link to the entire class in the main. Maybe this will help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the textfield.embedfont = true.  ?

Comment: Tried that, but if I put that the text becomes invisible.